# Modify a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to modify the raw data in `df1` to the form of `df2`

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame([["20180105","abcdefg"],["","sdasdas"],["20180211","asdasfsd"],["","asdfg"],["","sdada"]],columns=["A","B"])

df2=pd.DataFrame([["20180105","abcdefgsdasdas"],["20180211","asdasfsdasdfgsdada"]],columns=["A","B"])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can `groupby`, and use `sum` for string concatenation:

```
df1.replace({'A':{'':np.nan}}).ffill().groupby('A', as_index=False).sum() 

          A                   B
0  20180105      abcdefgsdasdas
1  20180211  asdasfsdasdfgsdada
```

Note I got rid of your blank strings in column `A` by replacing with `NaN` and then forward filling with `ffill()`

Comment: Yes, except you should only replace in `A` in case `B` contains empty strings too.  It's worth pointing out that `sum()` does what `+` does, which for strings is concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

Can also use `agg` + `''.join`

```
g = (df1.A != '').cumsum()
df1.groupby(g, as_index=False).agg(''.join)

    A           B 
0   20180105    abcdefgsdasdas
1   20180211    asdasfsdasdfgsdada
```